# Trying to call static block on category click in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a multi-store site. I am trying to call a static block on category click but it always shows product list. I have done this successfully so many times but this time its not showing static block. I have given all permission, flushed cache and re indexed the data also.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,
Go to 
`Backend -> Products-> Categories` Click any category, You can see the `Display Settings-> Display Mode-> Static Block only`. You can assign that particular CMS Block in `Content->Add CMS Block` in the same page. Check the screenshot for your reference hope this will help to you https://prnt.sc/jfzbeo